# Kotlin crashes during initialization - CollectionsKt.first

Tags: android, kotlin

I see a crash whenever my android app initializes a kotlin class. From the stack trace, I see it's from the static initializer of the `BuiltInsLoader.Companion` object:

> kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first
>   (CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.java:166)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoader$Companion.
>   (BuiltInsLoader.java:38)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoader.
>   (BuiltInsLoader.java)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.createBuiltInsModule
>   (KotlinBuiltIns.java:150)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.platform.JvmBuiltIns.
>   (JvmBuiltIns.java:56)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.platform.JvmBuiltIns.
>   (JvmBuiltIns.java:31)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.components.RuntimeModuleData$Companion.create
>   (RuntimeModuleData.java:54)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.invoke
>   (KDeclarationContainerImpl.java:35)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke
>   (ReflectProperties.java:93)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getModuleData
>   (ReflectProperties.java:32)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke
>   (KClassImpl.java:46)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke
>   (ReflectProperties.java:93)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getDescriptor
>   (ReflectProperties.java:32)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor
>   (KClassImpl.java:172)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructorDescriptors
>   (KClassImpl.java:186)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke
>   (KClassImpl.java:90)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke
>   (ReflectProperties.java:93)
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.create
>   (ReflectProperties.java:32)

The decompiled static block looks like this:

```
BuiltInsLoader.Companion var0 = new BuiltInsLoader.Companion();
            $$INSTANCE = var0;
            ServiceLoader var10000 = ServiceLoader.load(BuiltInsLoader.class, BuiltInsLoader.class.getClassLoader());
            Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(var10000, "ServiceLoader.load(Built…::class.java.classLoader)");
            Object var1 = CollectionsKt.first((Iterable)var10000);
```

Has anyone else experienced this crash? If so, how do you fix this initialization error?

Answer (score 4):

This exception can occur if a certain resource file, needed for `kotlin-reflect` to work correctly, is missing at runtime. The file is located at `META-INF/services/kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoader`. Please verify that no tools remove it during the build and it's present in the final application.

The relevant issue in the Kotlin tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20575

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoader'
}
```

Might help